Indicial notation of square of cross product
When I have a cross product of two vectors a and x and I want to square it, I write (in index notation):
$$
(\textbf a\times\textbf x)=\varepsilon_{ijk} a_jx_k\varepsilon_{ilm}a_lx_m
$$
$$
=(\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl})a_j a_l x_kx_m
$$
Now, I want this written in the form:
$$
a_la_mB_{lm}
$$
where B is a tensor. I tried multiple ways to achieve this, first just using $a_j$ and $a_l$:
$$
a_ja_l(\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl})x_kx_m
$$
where B has the form
$$
B_{jl}=(\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl})x_kx_m
$$
But this is totally wrong in my mind because if I multiply $B_{jl})$ out, I get things like $x_m^2$ which is just wrong because the tensor has the indices $jl$.
The second solution is just multiplying it all out. I get:
$$
a_l^2x_m^2-a_ma_lx_mx_l
$$
The right side has the right form but the first term would have to be 0, which it isn't.
I am very lost on this and I hope somebody can help figure out were I went wrong.

How do you "square" a vector?

I see, I have written it confusingly. What I mean is the dot product of the cross product with itself. Sorry for the confusion.

Proofread. Your first equation is clearly incorrect.

How so? It is always the i-th component and just different indices for the rest. And then I can use the identity for the permutation symbol to get the deltas.

$({\bf a}\times{\bf x})^i=g^{ii'}{\varepsilon}_{i'kl} a^k x^l$ hence \begin{align}
({\bf a}\times{\bf x})\cdot({\bf a}\times{\bf x})&=({\bf a}\times{\bf x})^i({\bf a}\times{\bf x})^jg_{ij} \\
&=g^{ii'}{\varepsilon}_{i'kl} a^k x^lg^{jj'}{\varepsilon}_{j'mn} a^m x^n g_{ij} \\
&=\delta^{i'}_j{\varepsilon}_{i'kl}a^k x^l g^{jj'}{\varepsilon}_{j'mn} a^m x^n \\
&= {\varepsilon}_{jkl} a^k x^l g^{jj'}{\varepsilon}_{j'mn} a^m x^n.
\end{align}
Write $g^{jj'}{\varepsilon}_{j'mn}=\varepsilon^{jm'n'}g_{mm'}g_{nn'}$ and use $\varepsilon^{jm'n'}{\varepsilon}_{jkl}=\delta^{m'}_k \delta^{n'}_l-\delta^{m'}_l \delta^{n'}_k$ to write
\begin{align}
 ({\bf a}\times{\bf x})\cdot({\bf a}\times{\bf x})&=(\delta^{m'}_k \delta^{n'}_l-\delta^{m'}_l \delta^{n'}_k)a^k x^la^m x^ng_{mm'}g_{nn'}\\
&=g_{mk}a^kx^la^mx^ng_{nl}-g_{ml}a^kx^la^mx^ng_{nk} \\
&=({\bf a} \cdot {\bf a})({\bf x} \cdot {\bf x})- ({\bf a} \cdot {\bf x})^2.
\end{align}

Its a triple product, free for the order of $(\cdot, \times).$
$a \cdot b\times c = a\times b \cdot c$
The triple product in $\mathbb R^3$ is invariant under all rotations of $(a,b,c)$ in its symmetric group.
$$(a\times b) \cdot(c\times d)= a\cdot (b \times (c\times d)) = a\cdot ( c \ b \cdot d \ - \  d \  b \cdot c) = a\cdot c \quad b \cdot d \ - \ a\cdot d \quad   b \cdot c $$
by the expansion of the triple cross product $a\times (b\times c)$, orthogonal to $a$ and the vector orthogonal to $b\times c$, so its a projection onto the  plane  $\alpha \ b + \beta \ c$
So we have $$(a\times b)^{\cdot2} = a^{\cdot2}  \ b^{\cdot2}  - (a\cdot b)^2 $$

$
\def\q{\quad}
\def\bb{\mathbb}
\def\E{{\bb E}}  \def\F{{\bb F}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\cross#1{\,\left[\,#1\,\right]_\times}
$Introduce the following isotropic tensors
$\q\E\,$ is the $4^{th}$ order identity tensor
$\q\F\,$ is the $4^{th}$ order transpose tensor
$\q\e\,$ is the $3^{rd}$ order Levi-Civita tensor
These tensors have very useful algebraic properties
$$\eqalign{
&\E:(ab^T) \;&=\; (ab^T):\E \;&=\; ab^T
 \q&\{ {\sf Identity} \} \\
&\F:(ab^T) \;&=\; (ab^T):\F \;&=\; ba^T
 \q&\{ {\sf Transpose} \} \\
&\e:(ab^T) \;&=\; (ab^T):\e \;&=\; a\times b
 \q&\{ {\sf Cross\ Product} \} \\
&\q\e:\e \;&=\;\; 2\,I \\
&\q\e\cdot\e \;&=\;\; \E-\F \\
&\q\e\cdot a \;&=\;\; a\cdot\e \;\;=\; &\cross{-a} \\
}$$
where $\{\cdot\,/:\}$ denote the single/double dot products, respectively.
The entire calculation can be carried out in terms of these tensors
$$\eqalign{
\|a\times x\|^2 &= \|\e:ax^T\|^2 \\
 &= (ax^T:\e)\cdot(\e:ax^T) \\
 &= ax^T:(\E-\F):ax^T \\
 &= (ax^T:ax^T) \;-\; (ax^T:xa^T) \\
 &= \|a\|^2\,\|x\|^2 \;-\; (a^Tx)^2 \\
}$$
